# Remove more than one space from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

TableA

```
id  Name
--------------------------------
1   Ram                  Kumar
2   Rajesh         A
3   Avinash        K     Bae
4   Kishore        Babu
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: remove more than one spaces from table

Comment: And also forgot to show your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB(id INT,  Name VARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,   'Ram                  Kumar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   'Rajesh        A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   'Avinash         K    Bae'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   'Kishore        Babu'
```

Now do the trick with `Replace`

```
SELECT ID
,REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE(Name,' ','><'), '<>',''),'><',' ') 
FROM #TAB
```

**Result:**

```
+----+---------------+
| ID |   NEW_NAME    |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Ram Kumar     |
|  2 | Rajesh A      |
|  3 | Avinash K Bae |
|  4 | Kishore Babu  |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: Happy to help :) @PujaMishra